# Japanese character not visible when parsed from XML into a text file

Tags: java, character-encoding, xml-parsing, domparser

Some hours back I ran into a wierd situation, where I need to parse a XML file which contains some Japanese characters. I parsed the XML and generate a text file from that. But there are some lost chinese word.
Now comes the weird part, the incorrect data which got printed in text file is bahaving little spooky, when I copy that data and paste it somewhere, the correct & complete Japanese sentence get printed.

> Sample input(in XML) : 横ツロ貿並ス濿忿㿂今6燃㿠㿘㿧

I can't paste the text which got generated in text file, as on pasting that become the valid data again. So I attaching a snapshot here. The line 1 is the generated data, and at line 2 I have copied the line 1 text(spooky here).  [image: text file]
Code:

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("D:\\Test\\test.txt");

File fXmlFile = new File("D:\\Test\\test_BULK.xml");
InputSource is = new InputSource(new FileReader(fXmlFile));
is.setEncoding("UTF-8");

DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);          
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

////// code to parse the XML according to requirement //////////
data = valueNode.getNodeValue();
fileWriter.write(data);
fileWriter.flush();

// closing
```

**Update:**
if I store japanese character in String variable and use FileWriter to write that string to file, the characters get printed fine in file.

```
String data = "横ツロ貿並ス濿忿㿂今6燃㿠㿘㿧";
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("D:\\Test\\test.txt");
fileWriter.write(data);
fileWriter.flush();
```

Comment: There is no text but encoded text. Each text file is written with a specific character encoding. Each program that opens a text file has to be told which that is. Some programs are happy to guess and sometimes guess wrong.

Comment: @TomBlodget updated my question. It doesn't seems to be notepad issue. I am using Notepad++.

Comment: Note: FileWriter always uses the system default encoding. (I would avoid code that uses the system default encoding unless you need your code to use a different encoding for different users.)

Comment: Are you sure the xml file encoding is UTF-8? Show the bytes in hex for the BOM (if any) and the first line, please.